# Database Security for Public Databases

Tags: databases

I recently moved some of my projects over a to serverless platform. I immediately noticed a few issues though. The biggest being database security.

Prior to this I had been hosting my sites and database on a single server with the database only allowing connections from the local network. Now, because of the nature of serverless and [by the requirement of the platform](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/databases#allowing-&-blocking-ip-addresses), I must allow the database to accept all incoming connections.

I'm not an expert in database security nor am I publishing large production applications (hobby projects that include use of a database), but what are some security recommendations or best practices for this scenario?

Is SSL, regularly rolling a strong password and proper user permissions sufficient enough to prevent brute force attacks on the database? Are there any other things I am not aware of? I had the comfort of using a firewall, but now this is not an option, what can I do?

Thanks.